# Transcribing native speakers using dictation tools - any suggestions to improve accuracy?

Tags: transcription

I tried playing this to iOS 7's dictation feature:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6jhgUWBlxQ

The accuracy was pretty poor at regular speed, I'd say 20%, at best. I tried slowing down the playback speed and it didn't help.

Has anyone used dictation apps/software to transcribe something like the above with better accuracy?

Comment: I would be really surprised if speech recognition were so advanced that it could transcribe Chinese with an accuracy higher than 30-50%.

Answer (score 4):

[科大讯飞](http://ime.voicecloud.cn/index.html) makes the best Chinese dictation engine so far. The accuracy is far better than Siri according to reports. I've tried with their IME. If you speak clearly with a normal speed, the accuracy could reach 90% in many cases, but using it against fast conversations would surely be a frustration.